# Refresh Token in Reactjs redux application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, refresh-token

i have react redux application
my issue when the token expired , i facing issue how to refresh the token and recall the api,
 this code i call when i get any API in my app

First action I invoke it's getWithAuth() and in this way I'm handling refresh token i know I'm doing wrong.

(The code is not working actually just I'm showing example) 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kdujea?file=apiManager.js

I want when I call getWithAuth or any api and I get result 401. I want refresh token and if I result 401 then logout.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [axios interceptors](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors) to handle unauthorized 401 issue in one place e.g.

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
return response;
}, function (error) {
  if(error.status === 401) {
    // do something when unauthorized
  }
  return Promise.reject(error);
});
```